# Implementing and running a 3D U-net for denoising of synthetic data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a u-net for denoising some synthetic images over time. My data is (256,256,128,1) which is 256*256 grayscale images over 128 time-steps(trajectory is random cosin). I have 120 images, so the whole dataset is of shape (120,256,256,128,1). I've added 5% random noise to this data for getting the noisy dataset. I'm using TF2 and I'm treating it more like Keras since I've just started.

Here's a summary of my data:

```
x_train (120, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_train_noisy (120, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_validation (10, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_validation_noisy (10, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_test (10, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_test_noisy (10, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_train_input (100, 256, 256, 128, 1)
x_train_noisy_input (100, 256, 256, 128, 1)
```

Now I wanna build a 3D u-net for denoising it. Where I give the noisy images as input and the original demonised as desired output and want it to learn the transformation. I'm new to this, so I used a simple 2d unet from github as a kind of template and adapted it.

-Here's my U-net: I want to know (1) If this u-net architecture is correct? (anything obviously wrong with it, etc?)(it's basically a normal u-net like the Ronnenberg one).

```
inputs = Input((256,256,128,1))

conv1 = Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2))(conv1)

conv2 = Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2))(conv2)

conv3 = Conv3D(256, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
conv3 = Conv3D(256, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPool3D(pool_size= (2,2,2))(conv3)

conv4 = Conv3D(512, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
conv4 = Conv3D(512, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)

up4 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(256, (3,3,3), strides=(2,2,2), padding ='same')(conv4), conv3], axis=-1)

conv5 = Conv3D(256, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up4)
conv5 = Conv3D(256, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

up5 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(128, (3,3,3), strides=(2,2,2), padding='same')(conv5), conv2], axis=-1)

conv6 = Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up5)
conv6 = Conv3D(128, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

up6 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(64, (3,3,3), strides=(2,2,2), padding ='same')(conv6), conv1], axis=-1)

conv7 = Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
conv7 = Conv3D(64, (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

conv8 = Conv3D(1, (3,3,3), activation=None, padding='same')(conv7)

conv9 = Activation('relu')(conv8)

#now the keras Model and compilation
unet = Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [conv9])
unet.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

-Now I'm trying to fit it:

```
    save_dir = "/Users/Jack/Desktop/unet_50" 

es_cb = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = save_dir + 'unet_50_synthetic_denoise_weights.{epoch:02d}-{loss:.2f}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5'
cp_cb = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = chkpt, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
tensor_board = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
                log_dir = "my_log_dir_unet_50",
                histogram_freq = 1,
                embeddings_freq = 1,)

history = unet.fit(x_train_noisy_input, x_train_input,
                   batch_size = 4,
                   epochs = 100,
                   verbose=1,
                   validation_data=(x_validation_noisy, x_validation),
                   callbacks = [es_cb, cp_cb],
                   shuffle=True)
```

-But I get this and it's been stalling like this for about an hour like this. I'm pretty sure there should be something like a progress bar going through epochs:

```
Train on 100 samples, validate on 10 samples
Epoch 1/100
```

-So here's what my questions:
What am I doing wrong that the fit is stalling( is it that it should take hours and the progress bar thing is simply lagging behind). I know that my computer(CPU) is definitely running something heavy.

-Do you see anything wrong with the u-net code?

-Regarding the batch size, and the splitting of data for validation, do you see any obvious mistake or a  way better way to choose the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the input you feed to your network (256x256x128 images) is enormous, on top of that you have 64 layers on the first level of your architecture. I guess, only taking into account the conv layers of the first level should allready aggregate into something like 10 to 100Gb of GPU memory which is way too big.

I guess that's the reason why it got stuck, I am surprised though that it does not broadcast any kind of error message such as GPU memory overflow.

I would recommand to decrease the number of layers of the first levels, and to change them with 2d (3,3,1) kernels (the kernel will only works on the dimensions of the images and not on the dimension of the time).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah you're right, it takes about 50 Gb. if I use (128x128x64) will it take 1/8th of the memory. Does the math of it work like this?

Comment: I would rather go smaller at first and then gradually increase the capacity of your model when you have something running